# draw circle on bitmap

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

i've written an app that captures a picture and saves it on the sdcard. i then can load that image into an imageview to display it. i'd like to draw a circle on the bitmap before i display it. the code below displays the bitmap but no circle, any ideas why the circle is not there?

thanks.

```
BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfo.inSampleSize = 5;
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageArray, 0, imageArray.length, bfo);
        Log.e(TAG, bm.toString());
        //imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);


        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
        canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawCircle(750, 14, 11, paint);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bmOverlay);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might check `bm.getWidth`. If you are using a sample size of 5 then your image will be 5 times smaller than the original, causing your circle to disappear off the right side of the image.

You could try:

```
paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 25);
```

just as a sanity check.

Comment: @matthew willis hey thanks it works now. Could i pick your brains abit as you helped before and you seem to know a fair bit about graphics. I've a slidebar above the image and would like to change and redraw the circle when the slidebar is moved. atm the image is in a imageview which in turn is after a transparent surfaceview in the layout. this gives the efect of the bar floating on the screen. i was thinking that i might need opengl to do this? which libraries would you use?

Comment: You should be able to simply listen to changes in the slide bar (SeekBar?) and then invalidate the view where you draw the circle and have it draw in the new location. I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: i'm wanting a circle on the image where as the seekbar is moved, it distorts the underlying pixels in the bitmap. i'm just trying to do it bit by bit. I've made the circle to have a transparent inner so i'd like to re-arrange the pixels only inside the circle, hope i've explained that ok

Comment: Hmm, actually I'm not very experienced with drawing. However, you probably don't want to use an ImageView for animation. Why not use a custom view and draw directly during `onDraw`?

Comment: @matthew willis hi, yep that sounds like a plan and is what i'm wanting to try out. Could you clear something up for me. atm i've a surfaceview in a relative layout with buttons after the surfaceview(so they seem to float on screen). like you said i dont need to use an imageview but rather a customview class then override the onDraw(). so far so good. But if i want a surfaceview with buttons(all declared in xml file), do i need the xml file when creating a customview and then passing that to setContentView() in my activity?

Comment: You can create your view objects in Java or in an xml layout.

Comment: @matthew willis so for example, i could write a custom view class which sets the bitmap as the background,set that as my view in my activity's contentView() then could draw on that bitmap and say place a seekbar all programatically? that way i don't need the xml file?

Comment: No, I think that the bitmaps you set via xml will be immutable.