# Draw circular sector

Tags: android, graphics, 2d

I want to draw a circular sector. I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531062/draw-circle-on-bitmap) how to do a circle, which is pretty obvious. What is the best way to draw a circular sector?

- Does exist any method for that
- I should do some geometry calculation in order to draw it by myself

Comment: Thanks, I need to check which works in order to accept an asnwer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you are looking for something like [canvas.drawArc()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a method to do what you want, but you can use `drawArc` and `drawLine`. Some info on how to compute the necessary coordinates can be found [in this article](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2009/01/02/Android-Draw-a-Curved-Line).

Comment: What about using drawArc with fill paint? It seemed to be a good solution to me, but I do not know if it really works

Comment: If you want it filled, and in the shape of a wedge, you can use drawArc, with the useCenter-parameter as true.